# Как добавить некие данные к определенному пользователю в таблицу MySQL на PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня есть таблица test, в которой хранятся запросы (любые).
По итогу, как мне сделать так, чтобы когда я давал ответ (кнопочка синяя), он выдавался определенному пользователю и вписывался в определенную ячейку данного пользователя
Все новые данные появляются в таблице *которая сама себя делает на сайте.
В общем кто в состоянии помочь, подскажите как можно все грамотно оформить.
Я только начинающий в этой сфере, много возможно не знаю.

```
<?php
$title = "Главная страница";
require "blocks/header.php";
include ('bd/bd_one.php');
?>
    <h1 class="mt-5"><?=$title?></h1>

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Обновлений пока нет!</h4>
  <p>Версия сайта: <b>0.1.0</b></p>
  <p>Последнее обновление от: <b>xx.xx.xxxx</b></p>
  <p>Что входит в обновление: <b>Пусто</b></p>
</div>

 <?php
 if ($username = $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['role'] = "1")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
 ?> 
    <table class="table" id="table-id">
    <thead class="thead-dark"><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Text</th><th>Дата</th><th>Ответ от сотрудников</th><th>Выдача ответа</th></tr></thead>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["text"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["date"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["otvet"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@getbootstrap">Дать ответ</button>' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
    <script>
        new Tablesort(document.getElementById('table-id'));
    </script>
</table>
<?php if(isset($fsmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fsmsg; ?> </div><?php }?>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Вы отвечаете: ??????</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Текст</label>
            <input id="id" type="hidden" VALUE="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="form-control" id="recipient-name fer obr">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="submit" id="otv" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Ответить</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$answer = $_POST['otvet'];
    if (empty($answer)) {
        $fsmsg = "Введите сообщение!";
    } else {
        if (isset($answer)) {
        $query = "UPDATE `test` SET `otvet` = '$answer' WHERE `id` = '{$_POST['id']}'";
        echo $_POST['id'];
        //INSERT INTO test (otvet) VALUES('$answer') WHERE 
        $row1 = $pdo->query($query);
        $user1 = $row1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        /*if ($user1) {
            $fsmsg = "Ошибка регистрации!";
        } else {
            $smsg = "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Можете перейти в ваш ".'<a href="../hello.php">Личный кабинет</a>';
            // header('Location: ../hello.php');
        }*/
    }
    }
require "blocks/footer.php";
?>
```

Ну и прикреплю сам вид сайта и MySQL:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается так, что нужно чтобы при ответе пользователю, данный текст вставлялся в таблицу столбца "otvet".

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В чём проблема-то? Вот тут `WHERE id = '{$_POST['id']}'";` зачем фигурные скобки?